# My entire view wont scroll, only my recyclerview inside my nestedscrollview

Tags: android, android-layout

So I've got this UI where I have an image at the very top of my screen, with two texts below. I want my text to overlap the bottom of the image and then below all of this, I have a recyclerview . With my current UI, it seems like the Text overlapping the image is just fine, but I can't get it to scroll. If I put match_parent on my recyclerview, I can scroll everything but the Text suddenly isn't fine.
I want the entire screen to scroll, not just the recyclerview, which is why I have it all inside a NestedScrollView. Hopefully someone can spot my mistake, I've been at it for too long and it annoys me. :)

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/some_icon"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                style="@style/TextView.H1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Overlapping Text"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/image"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.25" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/sub_title"
                style="@style/TextView.Dark.H5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Subtitle below Overlapping"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/sub_title" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Due to this being for a client, I can't show an image of the design. I've made a quick mock in paint trying to explain what I want. [image]

Comment: What do you want as your output exactly?

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin I want an Image, with the title being overlapping the button of the image. Below that I want a subtitle, and below the subtitle I want my list. And I want the entire view to scroll when I go down the list.

Comment: Haven't you any UI?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? I have the xml posted in the question?

Comment: No, I mean if you have UI of what you want, please attach it

Comment: I can't due to sensitive information :(

Comment: Change main information and post it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209432/discussion-between-mikkel-larsen-and-mohammadmoeingolchin).

Comment: By an image we will understand what you want better

Comment: I've updated the question with a crappy image of what I want. Had to use paint to do something quickly.

Comment: try to warp your `recyclerview` as `match_parent` height with `RelativeView` as `wrap_content` height inside NestedScrollView. this will make the desired output, although is not good to create nested scroll events in same layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated your code and used LinearLayout instead of ConstraintLayout. Check the below code

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_round_icon_48dp" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Overlapping Text"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.25" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/sub_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Subtitle below Overlapping" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: and for title overlapping you can use `translationY=-"30dp"` which would move the title on to your image.

Comment: It kind of works, but the issue here is the -30dp will make it look different on each screen, which is why I'd like constraint layout.

Comment: You can put the ImageView and both TextView inside a ConstraintLayout and align it according to your need, and then keep the RecyclerView below this ConstraintLayout. Hope this works out for you.

Comment: I feel like I've tried that multiple times. How would one go about that? I've added an image in regards to how I want it to look, even though it's ugly paint. :)

Comment: you want both the title and the subtitle on top of the image, or just the title on top it?

Comment: I want the middle of the Title, to align with the base of the image, and then just the subtitle below the title.

Comment: I've now changed it all so my recyclerview contains two types, header and item. So I just add the image, title and subtitle to the header and then the rest is just items. So now I just need to get the design for the Header. You got a good idea for that? I'm having a hard time placing it correctly on the center while having to avoid any +/-dp that might look different on different phones.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209449/discussion-between-graphicstone-and-mikkel-larsen).

Comment: Ended up using the translationY ="-30dp", but I'm not particularly happy with how it's done, even though it works! But it feels unstable, but it does the job for now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'll see if I can get it done in some other correct way, will update this thread if I achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Nesting scrolls was never a good idea. You should avoid this at all costs, one scroll messes with another. Reconsider changing your layout structure.

What do you want to do? Please, when posing questions that describe layouts, just attach images. I didn't undertand exactly what you want.

Comment: See my updated post, even though it's an ugly image I hope it explains what I'm after